# WIA flatbed scan

Tags: c#, scanning, wia

I'm using [this](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/printthread.php?t=439027) code to scan documents using scanner's feeder.
What do I have to change, so that flatbed is used?

edit: I removed the while(hasPages) loop and hasPages check... But somehow I must set that flatbed is used but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add this to switch statement:

```
case 3088:
    SetProperty(item, 2); // 1 = feeder, 2 = flatbed
    break;
```